# convert html to ms_word format

Tags: php

How can I convert "html code" to .doc or .rtf or another office file format in php for unix os?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/688524/html-to-word-in-php-problem-in-open-office-output

Answer (score 1):

There is a [PEAR library to read/write OpenDocument Format](http://pear.php.net/package/OpenDocument) which is also supported by MS-Office 2007 (or MS-Office 2000/2003 through plugins). And [here is an RTF library](http://www.phprtf.com/index.php/about/) for PHP. I don't know of any libraries that can write .doc files directly but that is probably because .doc files are very complicated to write.

You could also write out ODF or OOXML by hand. After all, it's just a zip file with a bunch of XML files in there. PHP has excellent support for manipulating zip files. I haven't read the OOXML spec but it's not that complicated to generate a simple ODF file by hand.